# Custom html content for core/email_template

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates, attachment

I'm using Magento's `core/email_template` model to send an email (as opposed to `core/email` as I want to add an attachment).

I already have a `$html` variable which I would like to set as the body. Is there any way I can do so, i.e not have to specify a transaction email ID? Here is the code below:

```
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>1))
->sendTransactional(
    $template_id, 
    $sender,
    $to_email,
    $to_name 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sendTransactional()` method just delegates to `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send()`, so just call the send method directly instead.

```
public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
```

EDIT:
You can use the Zend_Mail class if you just want to send an email with an attachment. For example:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom("email@example.com","From name");

$mail->setSubject("Mail subject");
$mail->setBodyHtml($html);

$attachment = file_get_contents("path/to/your/attachment.pdf");

$file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
$file->type        = 'application/pdf';
$file->filename    = $filename;
$file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$mail->addAttachment($file);

$mail->send();
```

Hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not trying to send a transactional email, I'm simply using that model because I have an attachment. It's failing the `isValidForSend` method. What do I need to parse through using the `$variables` variable

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I need to use the built in mailer function due to the fact that I'm on shared hosting. Otherwise regardless of if you set a sender, it is not the permitted sender of the server itself (if you look at the email headers for Received-SPF)

Comment: Magento uses Zend_Mail aswell, so that shouldn't matter. You can check `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` (so app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php) how Magento does it.